# Finding quotient of additive abelian group in Sage

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, quotient-group, sagemath

I have $G=\mathbb{Z}^3$, $H=\langle(3,2,4),(6,1,7),(2,3,6)\rangle \leq G$. My task was to find the quotient $G/H$ as the direct product of infinite cyclic groups and prime-power-order finite groups $(\mathbb{Z}^r \times \mathbb{Z}/n_1\mathbb{Z} \times ... \times \mathbb{Z}/n_k\mathbb{Z})$.

Doing it by hand I obtained that $G/H$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/25\mathbb{Z}$. However I wanted to check this result with Sage Math, and created these:

```
G = AdditiveAbelianGroup([0,0,0])
H = G.submodule([(3,2,4),(6,1,7),(2,3,6)])
```

However doing `G.quotient(H)` returned that it was not an implemented function yet.

```
sage: G.quotient(H)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-ebaeef77a3b4> in <module>
----> 1 G.quotient(H)

/opt/sagemath-9.2/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/groups/old.pyx in sage.groups.old.Group.quotient (build/cythonized/sage/groups/old.c:2910)()
    204             NotImplementedError
    205         """
--> 206         raise NotImplementedError
    207
    208 cdef class AbelianGroup(Group):

NotImplementedError:
sage:
```

The fact that I can only find documentation for quotients of *multiplicative* abelian groups is discouraging. If this is not it, what can be the way to find and thus check quotients like these in Sage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

If you look at the [documentation](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/groups/sage/groups/additive_abelian/additive_abelian_group.html) for additive abelian groups, it says

> Additive abelian groups are just modules over $\mathbb{Z}$. Hence the classes in this module derive from those in the module `sage.modules.fg_pid`. The only major differences are in the way elements are printed.

This is a clue that, if things aren't working, we should check out the `fg_pid` module instead. Going to the [documentation](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/modules/sage/modules/fg_pid/fgp_module.html) *there*, we see an example which is easily adapted to your problem:

```
# make a new ZZ-module with the obvious basis vectors
G = span([[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]], ZZ)

# make a submodule of G
H = G.span([[3,2,4],[6,1,7],[2,3,6]])

# take the quotient
G / H
```

When you run `G/H` above, you should get the print out

`Finitely generated module V/W over Integer Ring with invariants (25)`

which tells you that $G/H \cong \mathbb{Z} / (25)$, agreeing with your computation.

---

I hope this helps ^_^